# How to configurate EPiServer 7.5 CMS authentication?

Tags: authentication, episerver, episerver-7

When I installed EPiServer I left the default configuration for membership as MultiplexingMembershipProvider and role as MultiplexingRoleProvider.

After adding a new User and making them a member of a group which has access rights to everything from root, I am unable to login with the newly created user.. How do I give these users access to the CMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, Johan Kronberg for pointing me to the right direction. Here it is in case anyone is struggling to find out why it's not working.

In my web.config I had to add the group I created to be allowed authorization in the following line:

```
<allow roles="WebEditors, WebAdmins, Administrators"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the group to ui and possibly ui/admin location elements in Web.config. Also add the group to the CmsAdmins definition in EPiServerFramework.config.